# post xml data and retrieve xml response in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

what is the best practice or how do get a xml response from the following.

The documentation says

> In Order to retrieve the requested data from the system an XML message has to be sent via HTTP-Post within a parameter calles 'load' to the following URL

Simple Request Example:

```
<Request version="1.0">
<Header>
    <Security sender="ff80808109c5bcc00109c5bce9f1003a"/>
</Header>
<Query entity="ff80808109c5bcc00109c5bce9f50056" level="CHANNEL" mode="INTEGRATOR_TEST" type="STANDARD">
    <User login="ff80808109c5bcc00109c5bce9f20042" pwd="geheim"/>
    <Period from="2006-03-04" to="2006-03-04"/>
    <Types>
        <Type code="RF"/>
        <Type code="PA"/>
        <Type code="RV"/>
    </Types>
</Query>
```

How is this done in ASP.NET (2.0 - is 3.5 better for this?) with vb? How do I process the resulting response xml further? Maybe output it into a literal.

thx a lot in advance for your feedback... greetings

Answer (score 0):

You can LINQ to process your xml response:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(response);
Dim userDetails = From item In doc.Elements("Query").Elements("User")
Select item;
```